# Graph Theory: Walk vs. Path

Tags: graph-theory

I'm stuck with this problem. I'm hoping someone will explain better than all the explanations I've read about.

Why can a nonempty simple finite graph not have a walk of maximum length, but it must have a path of maximum length?

In a simple graph of say 4 vertices:
If you walk (oscillate) between 2 vertices for 50 times, that would make the length of the walk 50 times.
Wouldn't that be longer than any path you could possibly get from the graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve understood what’s actually happening but misunderstood the statement that a non-empty simple finite graph does not have a walk of maximum length but must have a path of maximum length.

No matter how long a walk you have, you can always add one more edge and vertex to make a longer walk; thus, there is no maximum length for a walk. A path, however, cannot repeat a vertex, so if there are $n$ vertices in the graph, no path can be longer than $n$ vertices and $n-1$ edges: there is a maximum possible length for a path. This means that there are only finitely many paths in the graph, and in principle we can simply examine each of them and find a longest one.